# How do I increase query page size of widget from the default of 100

Tags: widget, google-app-maker, suggestbox

I am using a suggest box to pull up and select records from a database, but it appears to limit suggestions to the first 100 records in the database. To be specific, the 101st record will not appear as a suggestion. I have read that "query page size" defaults to 100 records. Is this what's going on, and if so, is there a workaround?

Comment: Also be aware that app maker is shutting down in less than a year. Don’t know how much time you want to invest in learning it because of that.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED: I found "default page size" under the datasource properties under the datasourses tab of the datasource. Changed it from the default, '100' to an ample value.

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing the number to 0, that means all records would be in one page.